# Graph not starting at the right x-axis tick

Tags: r, graph, plot

Consider the following plot:

```
 x <- seq(from = 1.01, to = 1.05, by = 0.01) ## test
 pmt_test = data.frame(Amount = c(paste(0.01,  sep = " * "), paste(0.02, "r", sep = " * ")), Start = c(2,4), End = c(4,4))
 p = paste("(", pmt_test$Amount, " * (i %in% ", pmt_test$Start, ":", pmt_test$End, "))", collapse = " + ")
 res = Reduce(function(r, i) { (r + eval(parse(text = p))) * x[i] }, seq_along(x), init = 100, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]

 par(xaxs='i',yaxs='i')
 plot(res, type = "l", xaxt = 'n')
 x.labels = paste("Year", 0:4, sep=" ")
 axis(1, at = 0:4,  labels=x.labels)
```

[image]

The plot I obtain start from Year 1 and extends beyond Year 4. The intended graph that I am looking for should rather start at Year 0 and end at Year 4. It seems that the data is shifted and doesn't start at the right point for the x-axis.

Any way to solve that?
Thanks!

Comment: When you call `plot` specify the `xlim` to start from 0. E.g. `xlim = c(0, _the maximum_)`

Comment: Change `at=1:5` in your `axis` call. Vector indexing in R is 1-based.

Comment: @alexis_laz I have already tried setting xlim, it does not solve the problem!

Comment: @James Good catch!! Thanks a lot! If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `at=1:5` in your `axis` call. Vector indexing in R is 1-based.

```
axis(1, at = 1:5,  labels=x.labels)
```